# List all Resource locks within all Resource Groups with Kusto

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-explorer, azure-resource-graph

I am trying to make a query that will allow me to view every Resource Lock within our Resource Groups and I have gotten nowhere with it. I am very new to Kusto and help would be appreciated!

Comment: you probably want to provide some sample data (in a form of a datatable()) and the expected output to get a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 1):

As per my Knowledge, we can pull the list of resource that having locks in the subscription by using either rest Api or from Azure CLI

- From Azure CLI ,we can use the below command

  ```
  az lock list [--filter-string]
        [--namespace]
        [--parent]
        [--query-examples]
        [--resource]
        [--resource-group]
        [--resource-type]
        [--subscription]
  ```
- Here is the rest API, to pull the management locks, at subscription level

  GET [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/locks?api-version=2016-09-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/locks?api-version=2016-09-01)
- if you want to pull the Management locks at resource level you need to specify the particular resource group & lock name as well

  GET [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/locks/{lockName}?api-version=2016-09-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroupName%7D/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/locks/%7BlockName%7D?api-version=2016-09-01)

Comment: @NitroNation15 -  If the above provided answer was helpful ? If so could you please mark the accept the answer as solution. This could help other community users who have similar query in the future.